# matlab: turn an image plus a plot into an image that contains both

Tags: image, matlab, figure

After running the following code

```
figure(2);
imshow(BW);hold on
B = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
colors=['r']; %['b' 'g' 'r' 'c' 'm' 'y'];
for k=1:length(B),
b = B{k};
cidx = mod(k,length(colors))+1;
plot(b(:,2), b(:,1),...
colors(cidx),'LineWidth',1);
end
```

I get a image of BW with a red line boundaries. I now want to save the figure as an image so I can use, say, impixel to find the boundaries.
How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide example of your image. Difficult to imagine what you are trying to achieve and what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain you are doing something in a very roundabout way, but the answer to the only visible portion of your question is:

[imsave](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsave.html#responsive_offcanvas)